# Show that solving this equation is the same as m'th Fisher Scoring step

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, fisher-information

In my exercise we assume that $Y_i|X_i$ has distribution with density $f_i(y_i,\eta_i) $ for $i=1,...,n$ where $\eta_i=X_i^T$ is the linear predictor. The generalized linear model with an exponential dispersion distribution is a case with:
$$f_i(y_i,\eta_i)=e^{\frac{\theta(\eta_i)y_i-c(\eta_i)}{\Psi}}$$
It is assumed that assumed that $f_i(y_i, \eta_i)>0$ and we define that:
$$U_i(\eta_i)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_i}log f_i(Y_i, \eta_i)$$
and
$$w_i=-E(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \eta_i}log f_i(Y_i, \eta_i))$$

We introduce now the score vector $U(\eta)=(U_1(\eta_1),..., U_n(\eta_n))^T$ and the diagonal matrix W with $W_{ii}=w_i$

I have to prove that for the m'th Fisher Scoring step for solving the score equation amounts to solving the linear equation:
$$XU(\mu_m)-(X^TW_mX)(\beta-\beta_m)=0$$
Where here $W_m$ is defined in terms of $\eta=X\beta_m$.

I think that there by Fisher Scoring step means in the Fisher Scoring Algoritm? And I have found in my book that for the Fisher Scoring Algoritm:
$$\beta_{m+1}=\beta_m+(X^TW_mX)^{-1}X^TU(\eta_m)$$
But how can I show it's same solving the two equations?

See this previous question

[Score statistic and Fisher information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550648/score-statistic-and-fisher-information)

Comment: can you Taylor expand?

Comment: Yes have learned about Taylor expand but on simple examples. Can I use Taylor Expand to show it?

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I actually do not know how to do this exactly, but you can write $U(\beta)\approx U(\beta_0)+(\beta-\beta_0)U'(\beta_0)$ (Taylor expansion). Note the similarity to your second to last display.  Now take this and solve for $(\beta-\beta_0)$ and pull $\beta_0$ onto the other side, and note the similarity to your last display.  You must show that the solution to those two displays is the same, and this seems to be a way to connect them.

Comment: Now it makes a bit sense with the Taylor Expand. But I'm not totally sure. You use that $\eta_m=X\beta_m$ and Taylor expaned and get $(\beta)≈(\beta_0)+(\beta−\beta_0)′(\beta_0)$, it makes sense, and when isolating $\beta$ I get that $\beta=\beta_0+\frac{U(\beta)-U(\beta_0)}{U'(\beta_0)}$. It seems a bit similar to my Fisher Scoring Algoritm equation, but it's not totally clear for my. Can you help showing that is the same?

Comment: One thing is that if $\beta_n$ minimizes $U,$ $U(\beta_n)=0.$ Hence replace $\beta$ with $\beta_n$ in the Taylor expansion, and you will get rid of the term $U(\beta_n).$

Comment: Note also that something like $X^TX/n$ goes in probability usually to the expectation of the second derivative of $U$

Comment: I think you are getting closer.  My strategy would be to do this expansion, etc for a simpler function like a univariate $f(x)=x^2$ and then see how maybe the Taylor expansion works with Fisher scoring.  Then add randomness to $f(x).$